# ItemAdd event on a public folder on Exchange

Tags: c#, event-handling, outlook-addin

I have a problem with attaching an event handler to an `ItemAdd` event of a public folder.

> The problem is the event handler stops being called after a few
>   successful calls.

The code is trivial. I have a `ThisAddIn` class which creates an object which in turn attaches a function to the `ItemAdd` event in its constructor. The function just pops up a messagebox.

Please point me in the right direction. I simply don't understand where to look for the error.

Thank you in advance,
Anatoly

Here is the test code I try to run:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    internal static Outlook.Folder posts_folder = null;
    private static test t;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        t = new test();
    }
{

class test
{
    public test()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Attaching...");
        ThisAddIn.posts_folder.Items.ItemAdd +=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
    }
    void Items_ItemAdd(object Item)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show((Item as Outlook.PostItem).Subject);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code snippet .. how are you declaring the event handler.. are you using anything like EventHandlerVar += new someeventHandler or +- someEventHandler are you using a Delegate , a callcback.? it's hard to tell without seeing what you have thus far thanks

Answer (score 3):

Continuous googling did its job. I found how to resolve the issue. It appears I am not the only one who experience it.

I added the reference to Items collection of the folder I want to track to the global scope:

```
internal static class stor
{
    public static Outlook.Items i;
}

public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    internal static Outlook.Folder posts_folder = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // the code for finding a posts_folder is omitted

        stor.i = posts_folder.Items;
        stor.i.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Posts_Add);
    }

    static void Posts_Add(object Item)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("New item");
    }
{
```

Now it works as expected. Alhough I do not understand all the details they say it is a garbage collection issue. My event handler eventually was thrown into the garbage. The reference to the Items collection on the global scope prevents this from happening.